# Materialized view taking too much time

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, materialized-view

i create a materialized view fast refresh. it takes almost 45 min to create but it did not refresh in 24 hours. i tried it on with index and without index. i check the log of all table max record in log table is 2 lac. query is as under please suggest what changes needed

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON a WITH ROWID,   SEQUENCE (COLUMN USED FROM THIS TABLE)
/
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON P WITH ROWID,   SEQUENCE (COLUMN USED FROM THIS TABLE)
/
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON PG WITH ROWID,  SEQUENCE (COLUMN USED FROM THIS TABLE)
/
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON PN WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE (COLUMN USED FROM THIS TABLE))
/ 
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON AP WITH ROWID
/
CREATE  MATERIALIZED VIEW C_INFO 
NOLOGGING
BUILD IMMEDIATE
refresh fast with rowid 
on demand
AS
SELECT  
   A.ROWID ACTROWID , P.ROWID PREMROWID, 
   PG.ROWID PGROWID,AP.ROWID APROWID, PN.ROWID PNROWID,
   ...
FROM     A,    P,   pg,    ap, pn      
WHERE   
        p.id             =  pg.id (+)
    and pg.columname  (+)=  'Value' 
...
```

Comment: First, check and see if the refresh is actually fast:

`SELECT mview_name, refresh_mode, refresh_method,
last_refresh_type, last_refresh_date
FROM user_mviews;`

There are so many things that could be going wrong here. Have you asked your DBA to do a full session trace when executing a refresh? What data volumes are involved here on the 5 tables involved?

Comment: dear Phil thanks  for response i already checked from user_mviews it is fast refresh. there  are about 5 million plus records in view and 2 lack in view log.

Comment: 2 lakh = 200000 ?

Answer (score 4):

Your materialized is not defined with a [NEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54162) clause, therefore it will only refresh when you ask for it explicitely. You can use either [DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_mview.htm#i997194) directly or create a refresh group with [DBMS_REFRESH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10707/rarrefreshpac.htm#REPMA018).

In order to automate the refresh, you could program a job with [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) or [DBMS_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) (dbms_job is deprecated in 11g).

You could also define your MV with a NEXT clause, for example this will refresh the MV every hour:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  C_INFO 
NOLOGGING
BUILD IMMEDIATE
refresh fast with rowid 
on demand
NEXT sysdate + 1/24
```

Comment: Ah, I'd read the question as "hadn't finished refreshing in 24 hours" rather than "hadn't started refreshing" :)

Comment: i am not sure if it is sufficient to specify NEXT. I read the manual an I think it is also necessary to specify STARTING WITH.

Comment: @miracle173: from the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54162): *If you omit the START WITH value, then the database determines the first automatic refresh time by evaluating the NEXT expression with respect to the creation time of the materialized view*

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat: yes, you are right, i have missed this

Comment: sir me using DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH to refresh the materialized view. so i cant need next and start with.